# How to add a string to this function in Arduino C?

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I've been toying with this code, and been looking up solutions to this problem to no avail. I was told you were to add a string to a function like so in Arduino C++:

```
myFunction(String myString)
```

I've seen examples using this as well. This is the chunk of code that is having issues.

```
if (piezoV >= 0.25) {
    Serial.println(piezoV);
    // Serial.println(F("Playing track " + tracknum +""));
    String file = String(trackid) + String(tracknum) + String(ext);
    musicPlayer.playFullFile(String file);
    int tracknum = tracknum + 1;
  }
```

The code fetches this error:

```
musicPlayer.playFullFile(String file); - expected primary-expression before 'file'
```

I'm new to Arduino C++, and I am using experience from other languages I've learned to help, but I was wondering if SO could help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
musicPlayer.playFullFile(String file);
```

is not a valid way to *call* a function in C++. You *declare* the function with types:

```
void playFullFile(String file) {
    doWhateverIsNeededWith(file);
}
```

but you *call* it without the type:

```
String file = "./pax_singing_badly_in_shower.mp3"; // torture user :-)
musicPlayer.playFullFile(file);
```

Comment: I seem to be getting a new error which is referencing my library - see below.

`no matching function for call to 'Adafruit_VS1053_FilePlayer::playFullFile(String&)'`

Comment: @WillWam, that's a different issue, you should ask a different question. That allows the questions and answers on SO to be targeted at very *specific* problems. FWIW, the doco I found appears to indicate it wants a `char *` rather than a `String&`. If that doco is out of date, you should make sure you're linking with the file player libraries.

Comment: Ah, okay. Will do.